# If my IC is blown the decoupling capacitor is short when I test with a multimeter

Tags: microcontroller, capacitor, pcb, integrated-circuit, short-circuit

My MCU and IC got blown due to high voltage. I checked the board throughout and found that all the decoupling capacitors are short circuited (checked with multimeter on continuity mode.) Later I replaced the IC and MCU and the short was gone.

How does this work on a circuit level? What is happening inside that is makes a decoupling capacitor make a sound when I connect it to my multimeter?

Comment: All the caps and chips are between supply and ground and connected via copper traces on PCB. If you apply probes to any point, you are measuring all components simultaneously, not a single component. Your hypothesis about all caps being shorted is likely false.

Comment: don't be using the multimeter in continuity mode ... use resistance measurement instead ... continuity mode may indicate a short circuit where there is none

Comment: How do you know it's the MCU and not not some other component that's shorting your supply rails together?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It works like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJSCxS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The over voltage damaged the IC, causing a short circuit inside it between the 5V and the ground lines (represented by the red wire in the diagram.)

When you tried to measure the resistance of the capacitor, what you really measured was the resistance of the damaged IC.

When you replaced the IC, the short circuit between 5V and ground went away because the short circuit was inside the IC.

Comment: A good example of how a picture says more than a thousand words. And together they say even more.

Answer (score 15):

If the MCU was blown then there were probably short circuits between the V+ and V- pins of the MCU. The decoupling capacitors are in parallel with those pins so your meter is measuring the short-circuit of the MCU, not the capacitors even if you connect the probes on the pins of the capacitors.

Answer (score 12):

Continuity mode doesn't test if the decoupling capacitors are short, it tests if there is a short anywhere connected to the circuit. In this case you are testing the power rail for a short, which it will probably have if you blew up an IC attached to it. When you removed the shorted IC you removed the power rail short.

Comment: The beep of a continuity test doesn't indicate a short - just a low resistance - likely something under 40 - 50 Ohms.

Comment: @PeterBennett A short is a relative thing I suppose.

Comment: Perhaps we'd all have been better off if they called it a shorter circuit.